# How To Make A Random Slideshow Through Folders and Subfolders

Tags: images, image-viewer, random

I use FastStone Image Viewer to manage and view the images on my Windows 10 PC. It can slideshow images in random order within a specific folder. However, if the images are scattered through more than one folder it goes sequentially from one folder to the next.

Is there a way to make it pick images randomly through the folders and subfolders?

I could not find it on the net, so any help is appreciated.